# Android: Text flow to another view?

Tags: android, html, webview, textview

Hi is there a way to dynamically load text that is too long into a text field of a fixed line length, and then have the remaining text flow into another textView in another view? I want to load HTML data into a view and not have the user have to scroll but jump to the next view to see the remaining text.  Thanx for any input or suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this unfortunately.

Comment: Thnx. That's what I thought.  Can't wait until Adobe implements TFL into Burrito (they said they are working on it for their next build).